# How to add analysis services to my existing SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, installation, ssas, cube

I have my SQL Server 2012 installed and I want to connect to analysis services. When I get there I don't find any server to connect. Check the pic below:

[image]

How to add a server for the analysis services and connect to it? I have been trying for several hours now but I cannot do it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This would be better asked at Http://dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Looks like you don't have the Analysis Services component installed.

Comment: @RogerWolf I go to the installation to install it but it does not show on the features :/

Comment: @BesaNeziri, check the SQL Server Configuration Manager - it lists all installed SQL Server components in the "SQL Server services" node. If "SQL Server Analysis Services" line isn't there, it's not installed.

Comment: What version of SQL server did you install?  If you installed express, you won't see an option to install analysis services.

Comment: I install sql server 2012

Comment: @RogerWolf it is not there. How to install that node only

Comment: Which edition of SQL Server 2012?    Enterprise?   Standard?   Express?   Try going into "Services" on the box and see if you have an Analysis Services service, and if isn't started, then try starting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed SQL SERVER 2014 and I got the analysis services features